# Delete all posts in a table exept the one where big_image has a value?

Tags: sql, sql-delete

I want to delete all posts in a table except the one where big_image has a value?

I have tried almost everything but its not working!
This is tha last one:

```
sql3="delete from links where userId="& session("user_id") &" 
and big_image NOT IN (select big_image 
from links 
where userId = "& session("user_id") &" and big_image="& bgbild &");"
```

I would really appreciate some help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
DELETE FROM Links WHERE UserID = :UserID AND Big_Image IS NULL
```

And please parameterize your query or you may soon find yourself with no records in Links at all by way of SQL injection.

Answer (score 0):

delete from links where userId="& session("user_id") &" and isnull(big_image,'') = ''

Comment: On a side note - change the inline SQL to a parameterized stored procedure or you are ripe for injection attacks ;)

Comment: Thank you all for your help, its working now, remember the 11te comand, you shall not program when tired ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm overlooking something, but if you know the value of `big_image` you want to find (`bgbild`) couldn't you just use this?

```
sql3= "delete from links where userId="& session("user_id") &" 
 and big_image != " & bgbild
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi guys
I have tested with all of it and I cant get it working :-)

Now I have :

sql3="delete from links where userId="& userIdet &" and big_image IS NOT NULL;"

and instead of deleting all the other posts, it deletes the one with the image the second time I click on the button?

Comment: Oops — That should say IS NULL, with "not" removed.